# Uploading to azure blob storage from SAS URL returns 404 status

Tags: ios, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-mobile-services

I am using Azure Mobile Services API endpoint to return a private shared access signature URL to my azure storage container like so:

```
var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, key, host);

blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(containerName, function(err) {

    if (err) {
        cb(err, null);
        return;
    }

    // Generate a 5 minute access
    var expiryDate = minutesFromNow(5);
    var sharedAccessPolicy = {
        AccessPolicy: {
            Permissions: azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
            Expiry: expiryDate
        }
    };

    // Generate the URL with read access token
    var sasURL = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(containerName, blobName, sharedAccessPolicy);

    var urlForDownloading = sasURL.baseUrl + sasURL.path + '?' + qs.stringify(sasURL.queryString);

    cb(null, urlForDownloading);
});

function minutesFromNow(minutes) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + minutes);
    return date;
};
```

I then return this URL to my iOS client to upload the file and process it as:

```
client.invokeAPI("document/\(document.idValue).\(document.fileExtension)",
                    body: nil,
                    HTTPMethod: "PUT",
                    parameters: nil,
                    headers: nil) { result, response, error in
                        if let dictResult = result as? NSDictionary {

                            // Get the SAS URL to write directly to the blob storage
                            if let location = dictResult["location"] as? String {
                                let url = NSURL(string: location)

                                let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
                                let uploadTask = session.uploadTaskWithRequest(request, fromFile: localFile) { data, response, error in
                                    if completionBlock != nil {
                                        let success = (error == nil && httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
                                        completionBlock!(success)
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         }
} 

uploadTask.resume()
```

The iOS client gets a 404 response with a message of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>ResourceNotFound</Code><Message>The specified resource does not exist.
```

The container does exist in the storage account and requests to get blobs from the container with the access keys are successful. This new blob won't exist as it is a new upload, but why am I getting a 404 for a write request to the container?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to generate your request?

Comment: Updated question with details. I invoke the API from the azure mobile services client library which returns a JSON object `{location: 'location url'}` and then use that to generate the NSURL for the request

Comment: Do you have Storage Analytics logging enabled? If yes, you can look up requests made against your storage account and see if the SAS token was correctly used.

Comment: I am curious as to how you are calling a private container?  How do I pass the Storage key from xcode?

Comment: I keep the storage key on the server with my Azure Mobile Services backend. I call a custom API endpoint which generates the SAS URL for the private container and specific document and return this to the iOS client. The iOS client then has a 5 minute access url which it can download the file. Similar to this http://inessential.com/2014/04/22/mobile_services_and_blob_storage

Comment: Hi, I want to get the URL for the image or video I uploaded to blob. Couldn't find any function that bring back the URL any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution...

`let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)` produces a GET request and even passing it to `uploadTaskWithRequest` persists this request type, whereas I thought this call would change it to a PUT or POST request signifying the upload.

Defining the iOS request as

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "PUT"
```

was successful. And the response returned was a 201 created.

Comment: Hi, I want to get the URL for the image or video I uploaded to blob. Couldn't find any function that bring back the URL any help??