# How to upload images to Azure using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am developing an app which needs to store images in Azure using Swift.

Is there any example that will be helpful ? If not can you give me a suggestion ?

Comment: is your problem solved!?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple example.

1- Start here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage/

2- Get the SDK

3- Here is the code:

```
let account = AZSCloudStorageAccount(fromConnectionString:AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING) //I stored the property in my header file
let blobClient: AZSCloudBlobClient = account.getBlobClient()
let blobContainer: AZSCloudBlobContainer = blobClient.containerReferenceFromName("<yourContainerName>")
blobContainer.createContainerIfNotExistsWithAccessType(AZSContainerPublicAccessType.Container, requestOptions: nil, operationContext: nil) { (NSError, Bool) -> Void in
   if ((NSError) != nil){
      NSLog("Error in creating container.")
   }
   else {
      let blob: AZSCloudBlockBlob = blobContainer.blockBlobReferenceFromName(<nameOfYourImage> as String) //If you want a random name, I used let imageName = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, CFUUIDCreate(nil))          
      let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(<yourImageData>)

      blob.uploadFromData(imageData!, completionHandler: {(NSError) -> Void in
      NSLog("Ok, uploaded !")
      })
    }
}
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: Hi, I am doing same thing as mentioned in answer but I want to get the URL for the image or video I uploaded to blob. Couldn't find any function that bring back the URL any help??

Comment: Is there any port of this library to use it on MacOS ?

Comment: How to construct AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use their [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135733.aspx), but they're working on an [SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2015/04/01/help-us-shape-the-azure-storage-ios-library.aspx) right now.

There are a couple of examples of using their REST API on iOS. A cursory search brings up: [Uploading to azure blob storage from SAS URL returns 404 status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157264/uploading-to-azure-blob-storage-from-sas-url-returns-404-status)

There is also this example on Github - https://github.com/Ajayi13/BlobExample-Swift

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 11 and Swift 4, you can do like this:

```
private let containerName = "<Your Name>"
private let connectionString = "<Your String>"

do {
    let account = try AZSCloudStorageAccount(fromConnectionString: connectionString)
    let blobClient = account?.getBlobClient()
    let blobContainer = blobClient?.containerReference(fromName: containerName)

    let currentDate = Date()
    let fileName = String(currentDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)+".jpg"
    let blob = blobContainer?.blockBlobReference(fromName: now)
    blob?.upload(from: imageData, completionHandler: {(error)->Void in
        print(now, "uploaded!") // imageData is the data you want to upload
    })
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This is just an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I am doing same thing as mentioned in answer but I want to get the URL for the image or video I uploaded to blob. Couldn't find any function that bring back the URL any help??

Comment: @Ahsan do this 
```
let blob = yourBlobContainer.blockBlobReference(fromNamae: yourBlobName)
blob.exists { (error, isExists) in
    if isExists {
        let uri = blob.storageUri.primaryUri
    }
}

```

Comment: Is there any port of this library to use it on MacOS ?

Comment: @StNickolay did you find any library for MacOS? if yes please help me

Comment: @alex there is only iOS version of this lib exist, I successfully built it under MacOS, but as soon its only beta, it crashes intermittently. So currently only one solution is to use AzCopy executable, just spawn separate process inside swift.